# Interrupt Socket.Accept() with ReadKey() in C# Console App

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

I wanna to how to interrupt Socket.Accept() in Synchronous Server application with ReadKey(), something like : when i press Esc or Ctr+X key, it will automatically stop the Socket. Based on some reading, i know that after calling the Accept() method, application will be suspend until a connection received. cmiw

Here part of my code..

```
      Socket listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
        SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    try
    {
        listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
        listener.Listen(10);

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\t [wating connection from client...]");

            //Based on msd doc, application will be suspend after this method
            Socket handler = listener.Accept();
            data = null;

            //i wanna catch an Escape key here
            ConsoleKeyInfo keyx = Console.ReadKey(true);
            while (keyx.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape)
            {
                // Koneksi masuk yang di proses
                while (true)
                {
                    bytes = new byte[1024];
                    int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);
                    data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);
                    if (data.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }


                Console.WriteLine("Message Received : {0}", data);
                Console.WriteLine(handler.RemoteEndPoint.ToString());
                // Memberikan balasan pada client
                Console.Write("Your Reply  : ");
                String pesan = Console.ReadLine();
                byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(pesan + "<EOF>");

                handler.Send(msg);
            }

            handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            handler.Close();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you could actually follow two paths:

1. Change this code to use Socket.BeginAccept/Socket.EndAccept (with EndAccept method calling BeginAccept again to process more than 1 client). Then your while loop could just call Socket.Shutdown when your program-shutdown requirements are met.
2. If you don't want to utilize BeginAccept/EndAccept (but I can't imagine why), you could spawn a separate thread that would run Socket.Accept while the main thread would wait for the appropriate keys combination and, once again, call the Socket.Shutdown method.

Comment: As far i know the BeginAccept() & EndAccept() built specially for asynchronous mode. And i wanna make it for synchronous mode, it's for educational purpose.

Comment: OK, so the second option should be suitable for you. You will still rely on synchronous Accept() but the loop controlling the execution of your program will run independently.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Socket.poll command. When poll returns true the socket if accept_able otherwise check the input key and terminate if it is Esc.

For exmaple:

```
do
{
    // Poll use microseconds, waits 1 second
    if (listener.Poll(1000000, SelectMode.SelectRead)) 
    {
       // the socket is accept/able
       Socket handler = listener.Accept();
       etc ...
    }

    //i wanna catch an Escape key here
    ConsoleKeyInfo keyx = Console.ReadKey(true);
    while (keyx.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape) 
    etc ...

} while (true);
```